# WPF execute method from other window, control does not update

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net

I haven't developed on vb.net for a long time and at that time I was using Winform. I have started a new project using this time WPF. I am slowly learning about the binding but I still have an issue. I can't find a way to execute a method from another window and have the control to update.

Let's make it simple in that example:

Window 1

```
Class BOM

Public Class part

    Public Property partNumber As String
    Public Property partQty As Integer

End Class

Public Sub ExecuteExample(pnValue As String, pnqtyValue As Integer)

    Dim myPart As New part
    part.partNumber = pnValue
    part.partQty = pnqtyValue
    pnTextBox.DataContext = myPart
    pnqtyTextBox.DataContext = myPart

End Sub

Public Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)

    ExecuteExample("1072992", 5)
    
End Sub
End Class
```

Window2

```
Class win2

Private Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    
      Dim bomclass As New BOM
      bomclass.ExecuteExample("some string", 5)
      Close()

End Sub
```

XAML

```
<TextBox x:Name="pnTextBox" .... Text="{Binding partNumber}"/>
<TextBox x:Name="pnqtyTextBox" .... Text="{Binding partQty}"/>
```

This is just an example, when I click on the button in the window where the textbox are, they do update normally.
But when I call the method from Window 2, nothing happen, when I debug, I can see that the variables are there but the textbox don't show the text.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you are creating a new instance of the `BOM` window and call the method of this one.

You should call the method of the already existing instance. You could for example get a reference to it using the `Application.Current.Windows` property:

```
Private Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)

    Dim bomclass = Application.Current.Windows.OfType(Of BOM).FirstOrDefault()
    bomclass.ExecuteExample("some string", 5)
    Close()

End Sub
```